# IntelliJ IDE MissingApiTokenError: `snyk` requires an authenticated account. Please run `snyk auth` and try again

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, snyk

I have installed the snyk vulnerability analysis plugin on my IntelliJ IDE , but when i try to run the analysis , it gives me error as below :

[image]

Although i understand it is asking me to provide some auth credentials for my snyk server , but i am not able to understand where to provide it in the IDE . I tried to see if i can find any options to set the snyk auth from IDE toolbar , but i could not find any . Does anyone has an idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a very polished plug-in with regard to installation, I must say; apparently they just expect you to know that their CLI tool must be installed in order to be able to use the plug-in. No mention of that on [the JetBrains Marketplace Snyk plug-in page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10972-snyk-vulnerability-scanner).

But from the error message I just guessed and went ahead: [Installation instructions for the CLI tool](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360003812458).

For example, if you have Homebrew installed, run this from the CLI:

- `brew tap snyk/tap && brew install snyk`
- `snyk auth`

[image]

I later found out that the need for their CLI tool is mentioned on [their support page about the plug-in](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360004032317-JetBrains-IDE-Plugins), though. But it says there ‘The plugin will automatically download the CLI in the background.’

Once the CLI tool is installed, the plugin is a joy to use:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (I cannot try this myself anymore, because even after uninstalling the CLI tools, the plug-in keeps working) it might be enough to acquire an API token and enter it into the plug-in’s configuration:

- Create a free user account at [app.snyk.io](https://app.snyk.io/)
- Navigate to [app.snyk.io/account](https://app.snyk.io/account/)
- Click on the form entry field within the *API Token* box to reveal the automatically generated token
- Copy it to the clipboard

[image: Screenshot from user account page at app.snyk.io]

Go to **IntelliJ IDEA** ➤ **Preferences** ➤ **Tools** ➤ **Snyk** (on macOS; for Windows it starts with **File** ➤ **Settings**, I believe) and paste the token within the *Token* field.

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ preferences]